# Creating Access 2007 Subforms on a Tab Control

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

The main entity in my database has about a hundred fields.  I organized the fields between many tables and added a 1-to-1 relationship between the tables.

For data entry (and later data editing), I envision a "wizard" with a form for each table and a "Next" button to advance to the next screen/table.  The primary key would be entered on the first screen and subsequently passed to all remaining screens.

I have heard a tab control with subforms might be the way to go.

What steps should I perform to create this wizard?

**Note:** Use the following schema as a simplified example of my database.
[Sample Schema](http://www.sedagain.net/sample_schema.bmp) (can't upload images from work)

Comment: It's a very unusual entity that really has 100 attributes. My bet is that your structure is denormalized and should be broken down into a main table with a small number of attributes and a number of N:1 tables with repeating attributes. Certainly any time you resort to 1:1 tables is generally an indication that something is wrong (unless you're trying to implement a type/subtype structure, which doesn't work particularly well in Access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden TextField in the parent form which contains your primary ID.
For every of your subforms you just set in the properties that the subform is linked to the content of this textfield. This way you can get all your subforms synchronized.

Comment: Should I have a button on each tab or a button below the tab control?  What should the action of the button be?

Comment: You don't need any button.
As soon as your subforms are linked to a field, the content of those will be automatically updated as soon as the original field is updated.
You probably need to populate this field during your data loading.

Suppose, your user selects a dataset in the first subform. Then in the button "Next" you write the following code:
`Me.Parent.Controls("NameOfYourTextField").Value = YourPrimaryID`
then all your subforms on subsequent tabs will be sync-ed with that ID.